# Using generics with @Named in mapstruct 1.4.1

Tags: java, mapstruct

We had been using mapstruct 1.3.1 and the below construct in our mapper class would work

```
@Data
public class SourceClass {
  private SomeClass1 field1;
  private SomeClass2 field2;
  private SomeClassN field4;
}

@Data
public class TargetField {
  private SomeClass1 field1;
  private SomeClass2 field2;
  private SomeClassN field3;
}

@Data
public class TargetClass {
  private Optional<TargetField> targetField = Optional.empty();
}

public interface MyMapper {
  @Mapping(target = "field3", source = "field4")
  TargetField mapParty(SourceClass source);
  
  @Mapping(target = "targetField", source = "source", qualifiedByName = "wrapAsOptional")
  void mapParticipant(@MappingTarget TargetClass target, SourceClass source);
  
  @Named("wrapAsOptional")
  default <T> Optional<T> wrapAsOptional(T data) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(data);
  }
}
```

After upgrading to 1.4.1, I get the below error

```
Qualifier error. No method found annotated with @Named#value: [ wrapAsOptional ]. See https://mapstruct.org/faq/#qualifier for more info.
Can't map parameter "SourceClass source" to "Optional<TargetField> targetField". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "Optional<TargetField> map(SourceClass value)".
```

Is this expected? How do I make this working again?
We use Java 11 in our project

Comment: I am fairly certain that you are affected by https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2233. I really hope we can do a release soon with the fix

Comment: @Filip this used to work in 1.3.1.Final and the reported bug is for 1.3.0, so I hope that was fixed for us already, isn't it?

Comment: Based on the code I see am fairly certain that it is the same issue. Can perhaps test with the snapshot version?

Comment: This should now work with 1.4.2.Final

Comment: @Filip this does not work with `1.4.2.Final` as well

Comment: Please raise an issue in that case

Comment: Sure, I will create a POC and raise a bug

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, something seems wrong here:

```
Can't map parameter "MyClassA source" to "Optional<MyClassB>"
```

Why does it try to map **MyClassA** to Optional<**MyClassB**>. Obviously it cannot be done with the `wrapAsOptional` method.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting, but it worked previously. I have added more context related to the classes and fields used. Hope that clarifies the situation

Comment: There is no optional support see https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/674

Comment: @Maneki that issue is for something else. In 1.4.0 and 1.4.1 there was a regression about something that used to work. We fixed this in 1.4.2